# A function that return values from a structure in C

Tags: c

I have this struct in C language.

```
struct webit{
 char indice[10];
 int prid;
 double latitude;
 char date[20];
 double longitude;
 int xspeed;
 int rEvt;
 int alti;
 int seq1;
 int seq2;
 int presi;
 char cod1[5];
 char cod2[5];
 int iint1;
 int iint2;
 int x15;
};
```

and I have this function already putted before the struct webit

```
tramafunction();
```

this is how the function works: receive a string of delimited by commas and then split the data to a 15 diferent variables, this is an example of a string :

```
  /*¶bL0     L3,01,+08590323,-079343001,010215,00000000000000,-tN,000,012689997,001219456,000,7FF2,C07F,0,4,*/
```

Function:

```
trama function(){
  struct webit wbt;
  char buf[103]="";

  scanf("%[^\t\n]s",buf);
  printf("\n \n Trama Recibida=[%s]\n\n", buf);
  int z;
  z=strlen(buf);
  printf("TAMANO DE LA TRAMA: %d",z);
  int i = 0;
  char *p = strtok (buf, ",");
  char *array[16]={0};
  while (p != NULL)
  {
    array[i++] = p;
    p = strtok (NULL, ",");
  }

  for (i = 0; i <16; ++i){
    wbt.x15 = 0;
    if (array[15] != NULL){
      wbt.x15=atoi(array[15]);
    }

    printf("DATA: [%s]\n", array[i]);
  }
  strcpy(wbt.indice,array[0]);
  printf("INDEX: [%s]\n",wbt.indice); /*AND EVENTUALLY WITH ALL OTHER DIFERENT DATA TYPES VARIABLES*/
}
```

in the main

```
int main()
{
  tramafunction();
  return 0;
}
```

At the end they convert the 15 data types of the array into the variables of webit in this case defined wbt.  example "wbt.indice"

HOW CAN MAKE THE FUNCTION TRAMA RETURN ALL THE VALUES OF wbt. so I can use it anywhere in the programas, another function, another struct. etc

Comment: `return wbt;` should do it.

Comment: Note that a `scanf()` scanset is `%[…]` and the `s` you had after it is not part of the scanset.  In this context, as a trailing character, it is harmless though the input never matches the whole of the format.  If there were other conversions after the scanset, the `s` would make those conversions fail.

Comment: As chux mentioned, you can return a value of struct type from a function. Define the function as `struct webit tramafunction(void) { struct webit wbt; /* fill in wbt contents here */; return wbt; }` In `main`, you can assign the value returned by `tramafunction` to a variable of type `struct webit` like this: `struct webit foo; foo = tramafunction();`.

Comment: hi @IanAbbott I do exactly what yoou said but an error occurred.incompatible types when assign to type "struct webit"  from type 'int'.

Comment: Your `function` is defined to return the  type `trama` but we do not see either a defintion of `trama`, or `function` returning any value. The first comment from @chux would require `function` to be defined as `struct webit function(void)` Or possibly `struct webtech` as there seems to be some confusion with your type names.

Comment: @WeatherVane sorry man I fix the type names it was my error, really is webit.