# scan a value in the main and pass it to a function that convert that value C language

Tags: c

hi friends I have that this function in C language

```
struct webtech tramafunction();
```

this function receive a value like this

```
/*¶bL0 L3,01,+08590323,-079343001,010215,00000000000000,-tN,000,012689997,001219456,000,7FF2,C07F,0,4,*/
```

and then the function make this:

```
struct webtech tramafunction(){
struct webtech wbt;
 char buf[103]="";
 scanf("%[^\t\n]s",buf);
 printf("\n \n data destinated to convert=[%s]\n\n", buf);
int z;
z=strlen(buf);
printf("size of data: %d",z);
int i = 0;
char *p = strtok (buf, ",");
char *array[16]={0};
while (p != NULL)
{
    array[i++] = p;
    p = strtok (NULL, ",");
}

for (i = 0; i <16; ++i){
    wbt.x15 = 0;
    if (array[i] != NULL){
        wbt.x15=atoi(array[15]);
    }

printf("data: [%s]\n", array[i]);
}



printf("\n \t \t --data--\n");

strcpy(wbt.indice,array[0]);
printf("INDEX: [%s]\n",wbt.indice);


 wbt.prid=atoi(array[1]);
 printf("PRE INDEX: [%d]\n",wbt.prid);
 return wbt;
}
```

the main do this:

```
int main()
{

 struct webtech con;

 con = tramafunction();
 return 0;

}
```

the question is how can I make that the data to be converted(char buf[]) get read in the main and not in the function.

Comment: Note: this is a follow-on question [from this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39775122/a-function-that-return-values-from-a-structure-in-c)

Comment: In `for (i = 0; i <16; ++i){` why are you using hard-coded array index `[15]` in the loop and not `[i]`? This loop repeats the same operation on every iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to declare the variable

```
char buf[103] = "";
```

inside the function, in the header too

```
struct webtech tramafunction(char buf[103]);
```

in the main :

```
int main()
 {

 struct webtech con;
 char tr[103]="";
 scanf("%[^\t\n]s",tr);
 con = tramafunction(tr);
return 0;

 }
```